# A Groovy way to add/assign a map key?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

Is there a more "Groovy" way or a oneliner for doing this?

```
def map1 = [:], map2= [foo: "bar"]
if (map1.submap) {
    map1.submap << map2
}
else {
    map1.submap = map2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `withDefault`:

```
def map1 = map1.withDefault { [ foo: 'bar' ] }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of that one. Nice solution! Now I got another problem when doing a render as JSON to this map (in Grails app), but that's another story :D